# How to properly configure newrelic in Mule ESB 3.1.2

Tags: ubuntu, mule, newrelic, newrelic-platform, apdex

I would like to monitor my mule-standalone-3.1.2 ESB which is running on ubuntu server using New Relic Agent v3.1.1. I have several apps in the mule-standalone-3.1.2/apps directory. I have configured the newrelic agent in conf/wrapper.conf

```
wrapper.java.additional.4="-javaagent:/home/mule-standalone-3.1.2/newrelic/newrelic.jar"
wrapper.java.additional.4.stripquotes=TRUE
```

newrelic.yml is available in the same directory as newrelic.jar. Mule started successfully and I can see my application available in newrelic Applications dashboard as a java background application. The issue now is when I open the overview dashboard on newrelic, there is no data or Apdex score or any meaningful metrics. The only thing available is the throughput which is something like 488 cpm (call per minute). Am I doing something wrong or newrelic is not designed to monitor ESBs like Mule. All I want to see is how my mule application are performing and where I can improve them.

Thank you all,

Iyad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently New Relic do not instrument Mule, however you may be able to get some data by annotating your source with @Trace annotation depending on what information you are wanting to collect. A good place to keep any eye out for updates and possible changes to the Mule instrumentation is the New Relic agent release page. https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/releases/java

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mule 3.4.0 and just updated from New Relic Java agent 3.1.0 to 3.3.1, which is now displaying some metrics, e.g. Apdex, web transactions and external services, as well a displaying more tasks in background tasks than before.

You could also look into using [JMX](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/custom-jmx-monitoring-by-yml) to obtain useful data from [Mule](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JMX+Management), although I haven't had a chance to try that myself.

Also you may find it helpful to add the following to `wrapper.conf`, if you are monitoring more than one Java instance:

```
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Dnewrelic.config.app_name=MuleESB
```